# .gitignore still tracking files even if I tried to ignore them, why?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have the following directory structure in a project:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── ... <more folders & files goes here>
├── config
├── cronjobs
│── ... <more folders & files goes here>
├── oneview_symfony
│   ├── app
│   ├── bin
│   ├── src
│   ├── tests
│   ├── var
│   ├── vendor
│   └── web
├── .gitignore
```

I am trying to ignore some files and folders and this are the rules I have in my `.gitignore` file:

```
oneview_symfony/app/cache/*
oneview_symfony/app/logs/*
!oneview_symfony/app/cache/.gitkeep
!oneview_symfony/app/logs/.gitkeep

oneview_symfony/app/spool/*

oneview_symfony/var/cache/*
oneview_symfony/var/logs/*
oneview_symfony/var/sessions/*
!oneview_symfony/var/cache/.gitkeep
!oneview_symfony/var/logs/.gitkeep
!oneview_symfony/var/sessions/.gitkeep

oneview_symfony/app/config/parameters.yml
oneview_symfony/app/config/parameters.ini

oneview_symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache
oneview_symfony/var/bootstrap.php.cache
oneview_symfony/bin/*
!oneview_symfony/bin/console
!oneview_symfony/bin/symfony_requirements
oneview_symfony/vendor/*

oneview_symfony/web/bundles/
oneview_symfony/web/uploads/   
oneview_symfony/app/phpunit.xml
oneview_symfony/phpunit.xml
oneview_symfony/build/

oneview_symfony/web/css/
oneview_symfony/web/js/
```

Having the info above if I run `git status` I am still seeing files under `oneview_symfony/vendor/`, why? What I am missing?

Output example for the command above:

```
    ...
    new file:   oneview_symfony/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/resources/languages/pt_BR/Zend_Validate.php
    new file:   oneview_symfony/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/resources/languages/ru/Zend_Validate.php
    new file:   oneview_symfony/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/resources/languages/sk/Zend_Captcha.php
    new file:   oneview_symfony/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/resources/languages/sk/Zend_Validate.php
    new file:   oneview_symfony/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/resources/languages/sr/Zend_Validate.php
    new file:   oneview_symfony/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/resources/languages/uk/Zend_Validate.php
    modified:   oneview_symfony/web/.htaccess

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Comment: Do you have any prior commit which contains files under oneview_symfony/vendor/ ?

Comment: @Mark yes I think maybe I run `git add .` at some point and that's the issue

Comment: well, in this case, the answer by @xephox would be your solution.

Comment: @ReynierPM @Mark specifically the `git reset` part 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already added these files into your git repo and/or staged the changes.

To remove them from the repo, you can run `git rm -r --cache <folder-to-ignore>` to remove them from the git cache. (Make sure to include the `--cache` flag so that it doesn't delete the actual files too!)

If you've simply staged the files, you can instead run `git reset` to unstage them, and they should stop appearing in the changes list if they've been added to the `.gitignore` correctly.